# Jquery Cycle go to

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm trying to make this work dynamically on click but for some reason with a variable in there it doesn't work and just says

```
[cycle] unknown transition: 1 ; slideshow terminating
[cycle] unknown transition: 2 ; slideshow terminating
```

but works totally fine if I just use 1 or 2.

```
$('.go-to-issue').click(function() { 
   $('#wrap').cycle($(this).attr('rel')); 
   return false; 
});

<a href="#" class="go-to-issue" rel="1">Click</a>
```

Comment: As a side note, you shouldn't use "return false", you should use "e.preventDefault()". Of course you would need to make sure you actually pass the event into your function as such "function(e)".

Answer (score 4):

you probably need to convert it to an int, try 
`$('#wrap').cycle(parseInt($(this).attr('rel')) - 1)`
(the -1 because first slide is 0 I think)

Answer (score 1):

It helped me

```
$('#carouselnav span').click(function() {
    $('#scrollable').cycle(parseInt($(this).attr('rel')));
    $('#handles4 span').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the Pager example: http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/pager2.html

The pager features takes the user to a specific image in the cycle, which is what you want to do.

However, you might only want to implement a single pager link, not a link for each image in the cycle.